# Select rows does not match in one table(mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mariadb

How Can I query mysql and select rows which does not match my query ?
currently this is my sql If I want to select rows which match :

```
SELECT `user_id`
FROM `my_table`
WHERE `my_table`.`month` >= '201510'
AND `my_table`.`month` <= '201601'
```

In mysql this would select user_ids

what I want is to select user_ids where they don't have any record, a *broken* sql would be :

```
SELECT `user_id`
FROM `my_table`
WHERE `my_table`.`month` !>= '201510'
AND `my_table`.`month` !<= '201601'
```

to be more clear, mongo [has a nice $not variable](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/not/) which perform a logical operation, I want something like $not but in mysql(or mariadb)

Comment: `month NOT BETWEEN '201510' and '201601'`

Comment: What if I have only one month ?

Comment: `!>=` is not allowed, but remember `not greater than or equal` is basically `less than` so try `<` instead OR maybe you mean `not equal` which would be `!=`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use `NOT BETWEEN`-

```
SELECT `user_id`
FROM `my_table`
WHERE `my_table`.`month` NOT BETWEEN '201510' AND '201601'
```

In case of one value -

```
`my_table`.`month` <> '201510'
```

Comment: What if I have only one month ? in that case I can't use BETWEEN

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM my_table
WHERE month NOT BETWEEN '201510' AND '201601'
```

Answer (score 0):

One more solution:

```
SELECT `user_id`
FROM `my_table`
WHERE `my_table`.`month` < '201510'
AND `my_table`.`month` > '201601'
```

This is equivalent to (**answered by @sougata**):

```
SELECT `user_id`
FROM `my_table`
WHERE `my_table`.`month` NOT BETWEEN '201510' AND '201601'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the column for NULL value explicitly

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `my_table`
WHERE `my_table`.`month` NOT BETWEEN '201510' AND '201601'
   OR `my_table`.`month` IS NULL
```

because every comparison with a NULL value will return NULL. And NULL is neither TRUE nor FALSE.

A general answer for your question

> select rows which does not match my query

Encapsulate your query and use it in an 'NOT IN' clause

```sql
SELECT `user_id`
FROM `my_table`
WHERE `user_id` NOT IN (
    SELECT `user_id`
    FROM `my_table`
    WHERE `my_table`.`month` >= '201510'
    AND `my_table`.`month` <= '201601'
)
```

But that would usually be inefficient.

Surprisingly there is a way to reverse a condition the way, that NULL will be converted to TRUE:

```sql
IF (condition, 0, 1)
```

so your query could look like

```sql
SELECT `user_id`
FROM `my_table`
WHERE IF((`my_table`.`month` >= '201510' AND `my_table`.`month` <= '201601'), 0, 1)
```

It also works with

```sql
CASE WHEN condition THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```